# What term is used to refer to iPhone and Android games?

Tags: iphone, android, mobile, terminology

What do you call games developed for Android or iPhone to differentiate them from games developed for other platforms?

Comment: What do you mean by "category"? I suppose you don't mean game genre like RPG, Puzzle, Shooter, etc.

Comment: Yes not genre, i mean are they classified as casual or any other.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are typically called **[mobile games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_game)**, which covers a game that runs on a mobile device. This is distinct from console games (Xbox, Wii,...) and PC games.

In addition, most mobile games (but not all of them!) are **[casual games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casual_game)**.

Comment: But there is a wide gap between traditional mobile games made in J2ME or BREW, and iPhone/Android mobile games. I was hoping there would be a way to differentiate these two categories of mobile games.

Comment: A gap in quality maybe, but I have seen some pretty awesome older cell phone games, and I have seen some really bad iPhone and Android games.

Answer (score 2):

Mobile, but if you don’t like that, perhaps “handheld” (since mobile implies telephony, and things like a DS are also handheld).